# Handling null in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have a 3 tables on MySQL:

> Table 1: Person, with fields id and name
>
> Table 2: Product, with fields id and name
>
> Table 3: Transaction, with fields id, person_id and product_id

Now, I want to search an String to get a list of transactions that person name or product name is similar to it.

Here is how I'm doing that (java code using hibernate, jpa and spring)

```
String str_query = "select tr from Transaction tr where 
(tr.person.name like '%ANA%' or tr.product.name like '%ANA%')";
```

(generated SQL):

```
select
    transaction_.id as col1,
    transaction_.product_id as col2,
    transaction_.person_id as col3
from
    transaction transaction_ cross 
join
    person person1_ cross 
join
    product product1_ 
where
    transaction_.person_id=person1_.id 
    and transaction_.product_id=product1_.id 
    and (
        person1_.name like '%ANA%' 
        or product1_.name like '%ANA%'
    );
```

It is working perfectly well.

However there is one circumstance where it has a bug:
When I have a Transaction where either Person or Product is null, even if the other one matches the sql, it returns null.

Say I have a person with name ANA CLARA and a transaction with her id and product null, than SQL returns null.

On the pure Mysql here's what I would do:

```
and (transaction_.product_id=product1_.id or 
transaction_.product_id is null)
```

How can I solve it on Java side?

Comment: Can you please post a few lines of sample data, and the result you want from that data?

Comment: There's some SQL missing here... The transactions table doesn't appear to have any column named `name`. I suspect the issue is with the inner join operations to the other two tables. With inner joins, with no matching row found in one of the other tables, the query won't return a row for that transaction. I suspect we want outer join operations, but the specification isn't clear (sample data and expected output would clarify it)... and the statement shown doesn't appear to be valid MySQL syntax. (I don't think the issue is with handling NULL, the issue is with no matching row found.)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the support, I've updated my question with the generated SQL and more things i've found out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (not tested):

```
   SELECT tr 
     FROM Transaction tr
LEFT JOIN tr.person p ON p.name LIKE '%ANA%'
LEFT JOIN tr.product pr ON pr.name LIKE '%ANA%'
    WHERE (NOT p IS NULL) OR (NOT pr IS NULL)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks :)